# Json subset from a big json column pyspark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a big json string in a data frame column with ~ 1500 key value pair (few of them are nested). There will be excess of 1m records like this in a databricks table.

I want to extract only those fields which are configured and have that output in another column within a dataframe for further processing. What is the best way to do this in python / pyspark?

```
{
    "props":{"field 1":"value 1",
    "field 2":"value 2",
    "field 3":"Value 4",
    "field 4":"",
    "field 5":"value 5",
    "field 6":"value 6",
    "field 7":"value 7",
    "field 8":value 8,
    "field 9":true,
    "field 10":"value 9" }
}
```

The output should be in the below format in another column in a dataframe

```
{
    "props":{"field 1":"value 1",
    "field 2":"value 2",    
    "field 5":"value 5",    
    "field 8":value 8,  
    "field 10":"value 9" }
}
```

The fields - field 1, field 2, field 5, field 8, field 10 are configured. So the list might grow / shrink in future.

Comment: Have  you tried using `get_json_object` function?

Comment: Yeah! How should I use it for only those which are configured?

Comment: What do you mean by "configured"? You'd need to manually loop through a list of fields that you want to extract.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how to loop through the fields and read it from the json. Can you help?